# What EXIF fields are commonly populated and don't vary shot-to-shot on photos from the same camera?

Tags: metadata

For programmatic reasons I'd like to be able to group photos taken by a photographer using multiple cameras on a given day by the camera.

I'm thinking make, model, & software.

Though it's very possible someone would be using two Canon 1Ds, both updated to the same software version, just with different lenses for example.  Or the same lenses even!

Any suggestions welcomed, thank you!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is serial number of the camera. But I doubt that it is saved in EXIF.

Comment: @Alex.S: it is, at least by my Canon DSLR's.

Comment: I acutally only need stuff that doesn't vary in a single burst of photos, so this is what I've settled on so far:

identify -ping -format "%[EXIF:Model] %[EXIF:Software] %g %[EXIF:MeteringMode] %[EXIF:ExposureMode] %[EXIF:WhiteBalance] %[EXIF:Artist] %[EXIF:Copyright] %[EXIF:ExifVersion]" filename.jpg

It's maybe not perfect but I think it should suffice for my needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exif Data - identifiable fields](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/89333/exif-data-identifiable-fields)

Comment: The proposed duplicate has a different goal (identifying fraudulently attributed images), but the question of using EXIF data to "uniquely" identify shooter and/or camera is the same.